# focus after animate

Tags: javascript, jquery, focus, textarea, jquery-animate

i'm tring to focus a textarea after a animate effect with:

```
$("#textarea").live("click",function(){
        if ($(this).attr("class") != "textarea_clicked") {
            $(this).val("");            
            $(this).animate({
                height: "+=30"
            }, 150, function(){
                $(this).attr("class", "textarea_clicked");
                $(this).elastic();
                $(this).focus();                
            });

        }
    })
```

But it doesn't work.

How can i do that?

thanks

Comment: Is the textarea a real textarea ? Not a wrapper for some rich editor ?

Comment: Please note that `.live()` will no longer work in jQuery 1.9. Use `.on()` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$("#textarea").live("click",function(){
        if ($(this).attr("class") != "textarea_clicked") {
            $(this).val("");            
            $(this).animate({
                height: "+=30"
            }, 150, function(){
                $(this).attr("class", "textarea_clicked");
                $(this).elastic();
            });

            $(this).focus();
        }
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

I know it is an old question, but for sake of completeness, here is a code that does what you want:

```
 $("#textarea").on("click",function(){
    if (!$(this).hasClass(textarea_clicked)) {
        $(this).val("");            
        $(this).animate({
            height: "+=30"
        }, 150, function(){
            $(this).addClass("textarea_clicked");
            $(this).elastic();
            $(this).focus();                
        });
    }
```

});